# Give focus to a Window launched from a system service using CreateProcessAsUser

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, service, impersonation

I have a System service that launch an application using the method `CreateProcessAsUser`.

This service uses impersonation to launch the app in the active session. The Application is launching as it should, I managed to make the window appears on the front by using :

> SetWindowPos( &this->wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE );

But I don't know what to do so the app can have the keyboard focus. Even if the app is on top, as long as the user hasn't clic on the window, the keyboard input goes to the application below my app.

Comment: You cannot shove a window into the user's face.  Nor would that often come to a good end when the user is busy clicking and typing away in the window he's working with.  Good odds that he'll close the window by accident and never even see it.  The sane way to do this is to start a separate gui app with a Startup shortcut and signal for attention with Shell_NotifyIcon().

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I'm only trying to perform what my client is asking!
And I managed to shove the windows in user's face, now I need to have focus on this window :-p

Comment: What the client wants, the client gets.  I'll leave telling the client that they need to go shopping for another operating system up to you.  Windows 95 still allowed this, just in case that's attractive to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your application register a (carefully chosen) HotKey via [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) and then simulate the key via [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx)

In the processing of the [WM_HOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279.aspx) message, you should be able to "steal the focus".

Remenber: It's **BAD** to steal focus, but I fully understand the "what my client is asking!" part.

Comment: I'm not so clever, the solution was given some time ago by Raymond Chen on The Old New Thing. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/26/9445006.aspx