# How to paste data from clip board to focused text control in web page?

Tags: c#, c++, google-chrome, firefox, mfc

I am working on project where I want to paste data from clipboard to last focused webpage's text control(like text box for username or password).
The web page will be opened in `Chrome\FF\Safari Web Browser`.

This all task will be done on click of "Paste" button in my application.

I have handle of last used application including `web Browser` (Other than my application).
So can any one help me on this?

Sorry for bad English.

if any more information expected please comment.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to "activate" the target window, in order to really have a focused text box.
See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17456056/1374704) in order to do that.

Then, you'll have to fake a "Paste" keyboard command using [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

Comment: thanks @manuell It works. and solved my problem. I was having this problem from last 15 days. You Help me a lot.